# "InvalidTemplate"; Message Deployment template parse failed:

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

Getting the below error while deploying the template
Error code
InvalidTemplate
Message
Deployment template parse failed: 'Error converting value "Standard_LRS" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Common.Core.Definitions.Resources.ResourceSku'. Path ''.'.

```
{
              "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/,2019-08-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "locationName": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "StorageName": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "StorageKind": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "skuname": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "skutier": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "variables": {},
              "resources": [
                {
                  "name": "[parameters('StorageName')]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                  "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
                  "kind": "[parameters('StorageKind')]",
                  "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('skuname')]",
                    "tier": "[parameters('skutier')]"
                  },
                  "location": "[parameters('locationname')]",
                  "properties": {
                    "bypass": "None",
                    "ipRules": [
                      {
                        "value": "205.145.64.0",
                        "action": "Allow"
                      },
                      {
                        "value": "205.145.64.1",
                        "action": "Allow"
                      }
                    ],
                    "defaultAction": "Allow"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
```

### Edit

Able to deploy the template but not able to add the firewall rules.

Comment: Hi Nancy Xiong, Able to deploy the template but not able to add the firewall rules

Comment: yeah, correct In Hurry not checked the network ACL one. thank you

Comment: Sure, I am checking once. Once it is done, then I will do the same. Thank you

Comment: {\"error\":{\"code\":\"InvalidTemplate\",\"message\":\"Deployment template parse failed: 'Error converting value \\\"Standard_LRS\\\" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Common.Core.Definitions.Resources.ResourceSku'. Path ''.'.\"}}'.", again getting the same error

Comment: How do you pass the parameters object when you deploy this template? You could use parameter files to deploy your ARM template referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-parameter-file?tabs=azure-powershell#add-parameter-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, you lack adding [networkAcls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2021-02-01/storageaccounts?tabs=json#storageaccountpropertiescreateparameters-object) object. The ipRules should be included in `networkAcls` object and the `defaultAction` should be set to `Deny`.

**test.json**

```
{
              "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "locationName": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "StorageName": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "StorageKind": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "skuname": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "skutier": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "variables": {},
              "resources": [
                {
                  "name": "[parameters('StorageName')]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                  "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
                  "kind": "[parameters('StorageKind')]",
                  "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('skuname')]",
                    "tier": "[parameters('skutier')]"
                  },
                  "location": "[parameters('locationname')]",
                  "properties": {
                    "networkAcls": {
                        "bypass": "None",
                        "ipRules": [
                          {
                            "value": "205.145.64.0",
                            "action": "Allow"
                          },
                          {
                            "value": "205.145.64.1",
                            "action": "Allow"
                          }
                        ],
                        "defaultAction": "Deny"
                        }

                  }
                }
              ]
            }
```

**test.parameters.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "locationName": {
            "value": "eastus" 
        },
        "StorageName": {
            "value": "xxxxxx" 
        },
        "StorageKind": {
            "value": "StorageV2" 
        },
        "skuname": {
            "value": "Standard_LRS" 
        },
        "skutier": {
            "value": "Standard" 
        }
    }
}
```